# Voip push notification suddenly stop working

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Our application is using voip push notification. We use the below code in order to register with APNS

```
PKPushRegistry * voipRegistry = [[PKPushRegistry alloc] initWithQueue: dispatch_get_main_queue()];  
/  
voipRegistry.delegate = self;  
/  
voipRegistry.desiredPushTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:PKPushTypeVoIP]; // register
```

It used to work fine and suddenly stop working in the latest iOS version 9.2.1 and 9.3(beta). Now, the users are not asked whether they wish to allow notifications. Even though we are able to get the device token through this api call

```
- (void)pushRegistry:(PKPushRegistry *)registry didUpdatePushCredentials: (PKPushCredentials *)credentials forType:(NSString *)type {
```

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer form apple that we also need to use `registerUserNotificationSettings` in order to ask user for push notification permission.

Hope it can help others.